# Borders only come on top in Android browser

Tags: android, html, css, browser

I'm programming a website which is responsive. At the end of the page, I want to have a footer. I want it to have a border all around. If I look on my Desktop, everything's okay. With my Phone Chrome browser, nothing wrong. But if I go to my Android Internet browser, it only shows the top border. The left and right borders just aren't there, and the bottom border thinks it must be at the top of the footer.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance, 
Brent

Comment: Provide your code

Comment: you can do debugging remotely using google tools

Comment: @ILoveCSS I have the website online, if you go to [this](http://www.neurop.nl/brent/pagina/websiteopone.html) website on your mobile Phone > Android > Internet you'll see the website

Comment: @TGMCians Where can I find that one in my Android Browser?

Comment: @BrentMeeusen whatever web you are running on your phone, you can debug same through your laptop chrome using this tool https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/